# What are the factors that determine the clock speed of a processor?

Tags: cpu, processor

What are the factors that determine the clock speed of a processor? Since the speed of electricity is the same for all processors then I assume that how fast the binary data is transmitted to different parts of the CPU is irrelevant, then if it is so what are the other factors that can determine the clock speed?

Comment: The minimum cycle time cannot be shorter than the longest it can take to complete one cycle of work, so cycle time is limited by a combination of how much must be done in a cycle (less per cycle means shorter cycle times and thus faster clock speeds) and how fast each individual gate can switch (so using faster gates means a higher clock speed for a given amount done per cycle).

Comment: A very difficult question to answer. There are books and books on the subject. It determines on the clock design, semiconductor process including size etc, material, doping etc.

Comment: Actually the time it takes for data to be sent to the different parts of the CPU is NOT irrelevant.  It is a key component to maximum clock speed.

Comment: Factors? Even temperature can define what is the max. clock freq of operation in a processor. The question is too broad to answer.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvotes. Although the question is too broad to answer, I think it’s neither stupid nor off-topic…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum clock of a design is determined by its critical path, which is the logic chain with the longest propagation delay. Propagation delays are the central metric here.

The Pentium 4 is legendary (infamous?) for its long pipeline, that means breaking up all the logic chains into tiny pieces, each of which can run in parallel. This allowed it to achieve a very high clock speed for the time.

The P4 also showed that this simple solution has many drawbacks, so at a more fundamental level all the propagation delays have to be decreased. What is a propagation delay ? In the end it all comes down to RC filters. every trace and every gate has some capacitance and this can be charged only at a finite rate. The transistors and traces have resistance which limits the speed at which the gates can be charged. Beyond this, the power supply impedance is also finite, limiting how much charge is available to switch very fast.

To reduce propagation delays there is work on 3 fronts:

- The manufacturers try to make FETs which can be turned on with a low amount of charge while offering a low output impedance at the same time.
- The chip designer (or their tools) minimizes the propagation delay lost in routing/placing. The on-die power supply network and the pinout/package are also relevant factors, because the power supply impedance in the multi-GHz regime is largely determined by the back-end-of-line layout.
- The PCB designer assures a sufficiently low power supply impedance from DC all the way to several GHz, using proper layout. If this is not done well, a CPU might be able to clock high for 1 ns, but then fail as the supply voltage droops. So a real life clock speed depends on this, as you evaluate the clock speed usually for an enduring load.

As mentioned in comments, there are also other ways to tune propagation delays, that are beyond the design stage:

- reduce die temperature. This reduces most interconnect resistances but affects capacitances not as much. Therefore it reduces all the RC time constants.
- raise supply voltage. More voltage through the same impedance means more current, means charging the same capacitance faster to the threshold voltage, means sooner turn-on (turn-off is faster usually), and so shorter propagation delay.

Comment: Highlighting that basic point that electrical loading and driver slew rate is the issue,  standard engineering challenges, time of flight comes in to play elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Signal propagation across the die is quite slow, even when using metal. Fast architectures mitigate this by localizing signals within a clock domain, and use pipelines to break up long paths. This keeps the clock speed up at the expense of latency.

Other than that, speed is determined by how fast the FETs can switch, which is in turn affected by VDD voltage, threshold voltage, on-state resistance, and signal capacitance (gates and routing).

These all have a relationship to process geometry. On balance, smaller geometries will switch faster than larger ones. Halving the feature size results in about a 30% speed up by some estimates.